# Assign value to missing elements in XML when populating a datagridview

Tags: xml, ienumerable

I am struggling with how to assign a value to the XML elements that are not being populated in the XML. It is not a constant issue but I have been tasked with automatically assigning values regardless of their existence. Currently, if an Element is missing, the row is populating with no data whatsoever. What I have tried is `DefaultCellProperty` in the `DataGridView` to N/A, `IsNullOrEmpty` logic and an IF statement. Without having to recreate the entire project, is there a method to add to my current code to assign an automatic value to any XML element missing when the records are being read?

`Click Event` handler:

```
private void btnReadXMLdocs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var documentsData = GetDocumentsData(@"filepath to the XMLs");

        var receivedFilesDataTable = new DataTable("ReceivedFiles");

        receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("trans_nbr", typeof(string)));
        receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sequence_id", typeof(string)));
        receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("received_on ", typeof(DateTime)));
        receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("description ", typeof(string)));
        receivedFilesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("register_action", typeof(string)));

        try
        {
            foreach (var dataPiece in documentsData)
            {
                var row = receivedFilesDataTable.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = dataPiece;
                receivedFilesDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }

                dataGridView2.DataSource = receivedFilesDataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {

        }
```

`IEnumerable<object[]>`:

```
private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath = @"filepath")
{

    return Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
    .Select(XDocument.Load)
    .SelectMany(file => file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingLeadDocument")
    .Concat(file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingConnectedDocument")))
    .Select(documentNode =>
    {
        try
        {
            var receivedDateNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentReceivedDate");

            var SequenceNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentSequenceID");

            var descriptionNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentDescriptionText");

            var metadataNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentMetadata");

            var registerActionNode = metadataNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");


            return new object[]
            {
                (string)documentNode.Parent.Parent.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentIdentification"),
                SequenceNode != null ? SequenceNode.Value.Trim() : "0", (DateTime?)receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime"),
                descriptionNode != null ? descriptionNode.Value.Trim() : "NA",
                registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : "NA"
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new object[] { };
        }
    }).ToArray();
}
```

XML Example (`RegisterActionDescriptionText` element is missing from XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RecordFilingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServiceMessagingProfile-Definitions-4.0">
  <RecordFilingRequestMessage xmlns:fsrsp="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:FilingStatusResponseMessage-4.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0" xmlns:j="http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:juvenile="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:JuvenileCase-4.0" xmlns:niem-xsd="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0" xmlns:domestic="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:DomesticCase-4.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:criminal="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CriminalCase-4.0" xmlns:amcadext="http://www.amcad.com/NiemEcf/extensions/1.0" xmlns:i="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0" xmlns:appellate="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:AppellateCase-4.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:citation="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CitationCase-4.0" xmlns:reviewcb="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:ReviewFilingCallbackMessage-4.0" xmlns:civil="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CivilCase-4.0">
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueueId">484</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueue">Criminal Traffic Existing Cases</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:IdentificationID>14115049</nc:IdentificationID>
    </nc:DocumentIdentification>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-05-28T10:17:05.229345-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="REVIEWER">
        <nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonGivenName>re</nc:PersonGivenName>
          <nc:PersonSurName>re</nc:PersonSurName>
          <nc:PersonFullName>re</nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>51201</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>re</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
          <nc:ContactInformation>
            <nc:ContactEmailID>re</nc:ContactEmailID>
            <nc:ContactMailingAddress>
              <nc:StructuredAddress>
                <nc:AddressDeliveryPointText>re</nc:AddressDeliveryPointText>
                <nc:LocationCityName>re</nc:LocationCityName>
                <nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>FL</nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                <nc:LocationStateName>FL</nc:LocationStateName>
              </nc:StructuredAddress>
              <nc:AddressFullText>re</nc:AddressFullText>
            </nc:ContactMailingAddress>
          </nc:ContactInformation>
        </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
      </ecf:EntityPerson>
    </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
    <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <nc:IdentificationID>Filing Review MDE</nc:IdentificationID>
    </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
    <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
    <CoreFilingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0">
      <nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-28T08:00:00-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
      <nc:DocumentIdentification>
        <nc:IdentificationID>14115049</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_FILING_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T17:50:51.297-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
      <nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T18:45:13.8464904-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T17:50:51.297-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>URL/UNIQUE IDENTIFIER OF APPLICATION SENDING THIS REQUEST</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
      <criminal:Case>
        <nc:ActivityDescriptionText s:id="Criminal Traffic">re</nc:ActivityDescriptionText>
        <nc:CaseTitleText>re</nc:CaseTitleText>
        <nc:CaseCategoryText s:id="40781916535">831</nc:CaseCategoryText>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID>052014CT</nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID s:id="ucn">052014CT</nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <j:CaseAugmentation>
          <j:CaseCourt>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>05</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>28</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION_UNIT</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Trial</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>COURT_TYPE</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Eighteenth Circuit</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>JUDICIAL_CIRCUIT_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationName>re</nc:OrganizationName>
            <nc:OrganizationUnitName>Criminal Traffic</nc:OrganizationUnitName>
            <j:CourtName>Criminal Traffic</j:CourtName>
          </j:CaseCourt>
        </j:CaseAugmentation>
      </criminal:Case>
      <FilingLeadDocument s:id="DOC00001">
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText>CLASS EMPTY-CS-AAADH6K-CE- 1AAADH6K</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="DocumentGroup">MOTIONS</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="DocumentType">MOTION TO SUPRESS                                                                         </nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">101</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T18:45:13.8464904-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T17:50:51.297-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
            <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
            <nc:DocumentFileControlID>Class EMPTY-CS-AAADH6K-CE- 1AAADH6K.PDF</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
            <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00001">
              <nc:BinaryBase64Object>removed by RB </nc:BinaryBase64Object>
              <nc:BinarySizeValue>101864</nc:BinarySizeValue>
              <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>1</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
            </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
          </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </FilingLeadDocument>
    </CoreFilingMessage>
 </RecordFilingRequestMessage>
</RecordFilingRequest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your XML is also missing the `DocumentMetadata` tag and your code has a stepping stone problem.  Check out these two lines of code from your `GetDocumentsData`:

```
var metadataNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentMetadata");

var registerActionNode = metadataNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");
```

The first line is going to return `null` as you would expect, so you're protected there.  The second line, however, only works when predicated on the idea that the first line succeeeded.  When you try to call `Elements().FirstOrDefault()` on `metadataNode` it's going to throw an exception because `metadataNode` is `null`.  Thus you return a blank object array, and get a blank row in your `DataGridView`.

**Suggestion**

It's hard to tell if this will cover ALL scenarios, but you might be OK with what you have if you just edit this line:

```
var registerActionNode = metadataNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");
```

To something like this:

```
var registerActionNode = metadataNode == null ? null : metadataNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");
```

---

...and this line:

```
(DateTime?)receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime")
```

To something like this:

```
receivedDateNode == null ? "Whatever You Want To Print" : (DateTime?)receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime")
```

Comment: my issue becomes is how do I account for when the entire element(s) are missing from the XML? as with the XML example above, a section is missing. I need to set these `NullReferenceExceptions` to some sort of value to populate the missing field in the datagridview.

Comment: @clerktech Does suggestion #1 help?

Comment: that worked perfectly. One more question before I grant the +50 is that the date field seems to be another issue if it is missing. I need to account for the other 4 Elements that could be missing as well. I couldn't get your Suggestion to work for the others through, only the metadataNode Element.

Comment: No problem - check that out.

Comment: dang man.....you are good!!! It took me throwing up 50 points to finally get some help. lol!! one last item and I will approve the points now regardless. On that DateTime, if the Element is missing, how can I make the null equal to `DateTime.Now`? Boss just swung through and dropped that on me. If it were my call, I say leave it as null. :-)

Comment: Haha, glad it worked.  =)  You could just change `"Whatever You Want To Print"` to `DateTime.Now.ToString()`.  You may need to format it if you don't like how it prints it.  For that, see this guy: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Have something here "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.DateTime?'" Also, it says I have to wait 21 hours to give you the bounty.

Comment: Oh it looks like maybe you're trying to put an actual `DateTime` object in there and not a string.  Just change it to `DateTime.Now` and see if that helps.

Comment: @ ChrisBarlow YOU ARE AWESOME!!!! It workedThank you so much. Up vote this for me? lol!! :-) You'll have those +50 rep points tomorrow.

Comment: I actually already upvoted the question - you were at -1 before.  =)  Have a good one!